# Java работа с 'пробелами'

Tags: java, консоль, text

Вот код который добавляет производителя машины

```
    String empty = "";
    String manufacturer;
    System.out.print("Please enter car's manufacturer: ");
    do {
        manufacturer = System.console().readLine();
        if (Objects.equals(manufacturer, empty)) {
            System.out.print("You didn't enter car's manufacturer! Please enter again: ");
        }
    } while (Objects.equals(manufacturer, empty));
      carStorage.newCar(manufacturer);
      System.out.print("\nYour manufacturer is added!");
```

Но тут есть один такой баг, если я вместо пустого значения поставлю пробел, он его засчитает и код выполнит свое действие, и занесет его в carStorage. Вот я решил создать массив с моими 'пробелами'

`String empty[] ={""," ","  ","   ","    ","     ","      " и т.д.}`

он не сравнивает с этими значениями. Как по другому это дело реализовать это? Чтобы пробелы допущенные в начале не читались, и даже если пользователь ввел 100 пробелов, говорил что ты не ввел имя?

Comment: Я не совсем понел что ваш код делает, и кто пробелы СОЗДАЕТ! Если избавится от пробелов используйте у String.trim()

Comment: @ДенисКотляров Никто не создает пробелы, просто когда я запускаю программу он требует ввести имя производителя машины, если значение оставить пустым и нажать на Enter, он вернет обратно скажет что ты не ввел ничего. Нооо если я возьму нажму на пробел, и нажму на Enter, он примит его как текст, и скажет что твоя машина добавлена

Comment: @KryTer_NexT смотрите что ввел пользователь. Если после операции `trim` строка пустая - ничего не заносите в массив и просите пользователя переввести данные..... то есть сравнивайте не с `manufacturer`, а с `manufacturer.trim()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Оооо даа) Это то что мне и нужно)) Спасибо вам) Сработало)

Comment: @KryTer_NexT ну эту мысль еще Денис Котляров сказал в самом начале)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Дело в том что, я новичок, и мало чего знаю) Ваш ответ более ясен был чем его... Спасибо вам обеим, зато теперь знаю как убирать пробелы))) :D :D

Comment: Дану:))_____________________

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    do {
        manufacturer = System.console().readLine();
        if (Objects.equals(manufacturer.trim(), empty)) {
            System.out.print("You didn't enter car's manufacturer! Please enter again: ");
        }
    } while (Objects.equals(manufacturer.trim(), empty));
```

Comment: можно даже Objects.equals(manufacturer.trim().isEmpty());